# How to install multiple msi installations silently from cmd file

Tags: command-line, installation, cmd.exe, automation, windows-installer

I have problem installing multiple msi files form cmd file

I have adobe.cmd that looks like this

```
adobedc.exe /sAll
adobeair.exe -silent
msiexec -i install_flash_player_25_plugin.msi /qn /norestart
msiexec -i install_flash_player_25_ppapi.msi /qn /norestart
msiexec -i sw_lic_ful_installer.msi /qn /norestart
```

Adobe reader dc and adobe air insalls, but msi files dont installs

I also tried adding

```
cmd /c msiexec -i install_flash_player_25_plugin.msi /qn /norestart
```

Also had no effect

Can anyone help me what i doing wrong?

Comment: I believe msiexec requires administrative privileges to work correctly. Do you rightclick your cmd file and choose: Run as Administrator?

Comment: Your using the wrong arguments...[`/quiet`](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/msiexec.html)

Comment: yes, i am using administrator privileges, and when i manually enter same command, program is installed, but when i start cmd file its skips last 3 commnads

Comment: @Ramhound the q argument allows for more granular UI control, and n means no UI. /quiet may still show UI, it just doesn't require any interaction, while /qn means nothing visibly occurs on the screen while the installation is running.

Comment: Try using the full path to msiexec.exe or using "Start msiexe.exe" or something similar.

Comment: @music2myear - Wouldn't he still need /quit otherwise its just an installer sitting there without any UI

Comment: Not necessarily. If the installer required further interaction, possibly, but the point of MSIs have for a while been to allow deployment without interaction, and so completely silent installs are basically a default option. I've worked with these same installers he's using years ago, and they all handled entirely silent installation back then.

Comment: i found solution definitly problem with cmd and msi. workaround with for loop                   for /f %%a in ('dir *.msi /b') do (
msiexec /i "%%a" ALLUSERS=1 /q /norestart /log %SystemDrive%\install.log
if not "%errorlevel%"=="0" exit /b %errorlevel%
)

Answer (score 0):

I found solution.

Definitely problem with msi and cmd.

Found workaround with for loop

```
for /f %%a in ('dir adobe\*.msi /b') do (
msiexec /i adobe\%%a ALLUSERS=1 /qn /norestart /log %SystemDrive%\install.log
if not "%errorlevel%"=="0" exit /b %errorlevel%
)
```

within folder adobe all msi installations are installed